# Find the cdf of the following distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given that random variable X follows: $P(X=2)=2/5$, $P(X\in(2,t))=\frac{t-2}{5}$ for $t\in(2,4]$, $P(X=4)=1/10$ and $P(X=6)=1/10$ Find cdf.
How to do that? What should i add with what? I am completely lost with this question....

My attempt is:
$$F_X(t) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{5}+\frac{t-2}{5} &\mbox{if } t\in[2,4) \\
9/10 & \mbox{if } t\in[4,6)  \\
1 & \mbox{if } t\in[6,\infty)\end{cases}  $$
**EDIT:** Question still remain unanswered.

Comment: You should describe $P(X\leq n)$ for $n=2,4,6$. Though clearly something is wrong with the data that you have provided (or more doubtfully, have been provided). It indicates that $P(X=2)$ is equal to both $\frac25$ and $0$, and that $P(X=4)$ is equal to both $\frac25$ and $\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: You should add $0 \ if \ t<2$

Comment: Data are perfectly fine. I think you misinterpret them.

Comment: The task and the information on the random variable $X$ seem correct to me. However, since $X$ is a mixture of discrete and continuous random variable, you will have to calculate $P(X \leq t)$ for $t \in \mathbb R$ or $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Is my attempt to solve this question correct or not?

Comment: Yes, It is correct.

Comment: Thank you! appreciate your time

Comment: You should add $0$ for $t<2$ or $t \in (-\infty, 2)$ in your solution, as @kmitov suggested.

Comment: I know, I know/